# Android app is not visible on tab on playstore

Tags: android

I have published the app on the Google play store. I am able to download and install on android phones. But the app is not at all listed in Play store for tablet devices. I suspect there is something wrong in my manifest file. contents of the manifest file are

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="true" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Please suggest what can be the reason here.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following properties in your manifest as per your application requirement.

```
 <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                      android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                      android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                      android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Hope this will help you.